# Is the current directory default static library, dynamic library, and header search paths for gcc?

Tags: c, gcc

Introduction to GCC has an example:

> ```
> $ gcc -Wall -L. main.c -lhello -o hello
> ```
>
> The option ‘-L.’ is needed to add the current directory to the library search path.

Does it mean that the current directory is not a default search path for **static library files**, so needs to be added to the library search path by `-L.`?

Similar question for **dynamic library** file search. Is the current directory is   a default search path for  dynamic library files, or do we need to add the current directory to the dynamic library search paths by `--rpath .`?

Similar question for **header file** search. Is the current directory is   a default search path for header files , or do we need to add the current directory to the header search paths by `-I.`?
Does the following example imply that the current directory is   a default search path for  header files , and we don't need to add the current directory to the header search paths by `-I.`?

```
$ ls main.c hello.h
hello.h  main.c

$ cat main.c
#include "hello.h"
int
main (void)
{
  hello ("world");
  return 0;
}

$ gcc -c main.c
$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current working directory is not part of the compiler's default library or header search paths.

However, includes of the form `#include "file"` (with quotation marks) will always search the current working directory, regardless of whether it is on the header search path or not. As such, `-I.` is only necessary if you are including files in the project directory using `#include <file>` (which you really shouldn't do, because it'll confuse anyone trying to read your code).

Comment: Thanks. (1)  In "The current working directory is not part of the default library or header search paths", do you mean both static and dynamic library search paths by "library"?  (2)  Does `#include "file"` search the default system paths? (3) Do both `gcc -L` and `C_INCLUDE_PATH`     affect both `#include "file"` and `#include <file>`?

Comment: The bit about the `#include "file"` is misleading.  Such include directives search all the same locations that the other form does, but they *may* first search one or more other, implementation-defined directories.  Some implementations, including GCC, do in that case search the directory containing the source file (first).  Some search the working directory instead, or in addition.

Comment: Headers enclosed in `"double-quotes.h"` are first looked for in some additional places (such as the current directory, or the directory where the source file is, or where the current header was found if dealing with nested headers), and then in the same list of places as if they had been enclosed in `<angle-brackets.h>`.  The C standard mandates "extra places, then same as angle-brackets"; it doesn't stipulate what those extra places are.  POSIX does stipulate (at least some) of the extra places.

Comment: @Tim 1) Dynamic library search paths are resolved… well, dynamically, at runtime. Linker flags can influence how the search happens, but the details tend to be highly system-dependent. 2) Addressed by others and in edit. 3) Assuming you meant `-I` and not `-L` (which only applies to libraries), yes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  Thanks. "Headers enclosed in `"double-quotes.h"` are first looked for in some additional places (such as the current directory, or the directory where the source file is, or where the current header was found if dealing with nested headers), and then in the same list of places as if they had been enclosed in `<angle-brackets.h>`".   For `"double-quotes.h"`, does gcc search the current directory before  the directories specified by `gcc -I` and  `C_INCLUDE_PATH`?

Comment: @Tim: See the GCC documentation on [Include Operation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Operation.html#Include-Operation) — which is based on the POSIX specification for [`c99`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/c99.html).  That's still used because the current edition of POSIX was introduced in 2008, several years before the C11 standard was finalized.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sorry if I wasn't clear. For `#include "double-quotes.h"`, does gcc search for `double-quotes.h` in some special directory (such as the current directory, or the directory where the source file is, or where the current header was found if dealing with nested headers) **before** the directories specified by `gcc -I` and `C_INCLUDE_PATH`?

Comment: @Tim: You were clear — I pointed you to the documentation from which you can find the answer, which is too big for a comment.  Roughly, "yes", but the details matter, so you should learn how to read the documentation. It depends on where the source file (top-level `.c` file) is located; it depends on whether the `#include` line is in that source file or in a header it included, or …  It depends on the command line options — and there are quite a lot of those, too (see also [Directory options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.3.0/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options)).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I read the two links in your previous comment, but couldn't find answer to my qustion. So I tried to clarify.