# Does `#include "FILE.h"` make gcc search for FILE.h in the current directory or somewhere else?

Tags: c, gcc

An Introduction to GCC by Brian Gough says

> Incidentally, the diﬀerence between the two forms of the include state-
>   ment `#include "FILE.h"` and `#include <FILE.h>` is that the former
>   searches for `FILE.h` in **the current directory** before looking in the system header ﬁle directories. The include statement `#include <FILE.h>`
>   searches the system header ﬁles, but does not look in the current directory by default.

But the following example seems to imply  the directory containing the source file being compiled, instead of the current directory. What is  correct?

```
$ mv src/hello.h .
$ gcc  -c src/main.c
src/main.c:1:10: fatal error: hello.h: No such file or directory
 #include "hello.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
$ mv hello.h src/
$ gcc  -c src/main.c
$
```

Comment: See also the commentary after the answer to [Is the current directory default static library, dynamic library, and header search paths for gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55659701/is-the-current-directory-default-static-library-dynamic-library-and-header-sea)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html states that

> By default, the preprocessor looks for header files included by the quote form of the directive `#include "file"` first relative to the directory of the current file, and then in a preconfigured list of standard system directories. For example, if `/usr/include/sys/stat.h` contains `#include "types.h"`, GCC looks for `types.h` first in `/usr/include/sys`, then in its usual search path.
>
> For the angle-bracket form `#include <file>`, the preprocessor’s default behavior is to look only in the standard system directories.

The document you are reading is therefore incorrect.  Perhaps Mr. Gough has never attempted to write a [nonrecursive Makefile](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf), or separate his source and object directories, and has therefore never noticed that "the current directory" and "the directory containing the current file" are not necessarily the same thing.

GCC has a whole bunch of command line options that you can use to reconfigure how `#include` works.  There is even an option that turns *off* looking in the directory of the current file (`-I-`), but it is not usable on many operating systems because it will break the C library's headers.